# VPC Image to Boot Natively

Tags: operating-systems, microsoft-virtual-pc

I have a VPC that I would like to host natively. Are there conversion tools available to convert an existing VPC image to something I can boot to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit difficult, but if you're running the Windows 7 RC or beta you can boot directly from the VPC 2007 images.

http://blogs.msdn.com/cesardelatorre/archive/2009/01/11/windows-7-natively-booting-from-a-vhd-virtual-pc-image-file.aspx

Comment: From the comments, it appears that some people are still having problems configuring it. I'll try this tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best best is to create an image of the virtual PC with something like [Ghost](http://shop.symantecstore.com/store/symnahho/en_US/DisplayProductDetailsPage/ThemeID.106300/productID.90124600) and then restore that on the real PC.  It will have to go through a whole round of driver installation, but it should work in principle.